# Is it on topic to ask questions about the private life - movie character connection of actors?

Tags: discussion, scope

A friend recently told me that the Californication character of David Duchovny messed up his marriage. Is it on topic to ask questions about the private life - movie character connection of actors? Or is this site limitted to movie stories.

Answer (score 9):

That's a very borderline question. If it is phrased differently, like how did the characterization affect the actor, and in return how did that affect the show (cancellation, recasting, story changes, etc) it would be more on topic. If it is only asking how it affected the actor privately, then likely not.

as with any border case, phrasing and quality will attract people who vote to close or vote to reopen if it does get closed. There is no guarantee.

Comment: I will make a try and link it here